# CMB2 datepicker - overwrite default values

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, cmb2

according to the CMB2 document I can use the following parameter:

```
'date_format' => __( 'd-m-Y', 'cmb2' )
```

it seems that it ignore it

checking the code I see that there is a function for localized the datepicker parameters but I did not manage doing it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
'date_format' => 'd-m-Y'
```

because __() is searching for a localized string of course